# ORA-01503 CREATE CONTROLFILE FAILED... while trying to create a database

Tags: oracle, installation, instance

i am trying to create a new database along with another database. The server already has a database running. I used DBCA command to create the new db instance. First i set the new SID and home and then ran the dbca command.. But half way through installation im getting the error

ORA-01503 CREATE CONTROLFILE FAILED

ORA- 01158: database already mounted

Comment: Either that file exists or you have permission issues.  What are your control files as defined in your init.ora?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could check the newly created init/spfile (under; linux: $OB/dbs - or - win: $OB\database) if everything is set correctly (SID and Service Name, Datafile location...)

I also would advise you to check all your env. vars, the error says “*Database already mounted”* - it seems it’s trying to create a .ctl for your already-running database.

You can try this to start fresh;

**Linux**

- copy your actual .profile in .profile_new
- modify .profile_new as per your need (*$OH*, *$ORACLE_SID*,...)
- `./profile new`
- check you’re all set: `env`
- start dbca again

**Windows**

- open cmd as Admin
- `set ORACLE_SID=[your new SID]`
- `set ORACLE_HOME=[your new $OH]`
- run dbca

Last thing, i would take a look at the oraInventory/oraInst.lok file, to check if there’s the old $OH set - if yes, move the file away (just to backup it) and restart the dbca.

Hope one of this solutions helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..it worked now....when i got this error first ..i tried creating another database...so the error kept coming ...When i checked i saw, eventhough the installation failed with this error ,the database got created ..So i used DBCA to delete the created database ...and set the env properly...then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 19c

I had this same error, after I did it manually, I stopped in this message:

**ORA-01127: database name 'o193lhml34' exceeds the 8 character length limit**

When you install a new database by DBCA, the DBCA does not block or show a error message when you try put a long name.
If you put a long name, you have a during installation.